# Flutter web Save as File

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutter-web

In flutter web, I created **app.js** file and used that in the flutter project.
When I release the project and publish it in the IIS javascript function not work.
It's working when I run the project debug or flutter run -d chrome --release.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showSaveFilePicker

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 ...
 ...
<script src="app.js" defer></script>

<script>
// The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
</script>
<!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
<script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
...
...
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
async function saveFile(blob, fileName) {
const opts = {
    suggestedName: fileName,
    types: [{
        description: 'Text file',
        accept: { 'text/plain': ['.txt'] },
    }],
};

// create a new handle
const newHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker(opts);

// create a FileSystemWritableFileStream to write to
const writableStream = await newHandle.createWritable();

// write our file
await writableStream.write(blob);

// close the file and write the contents to disk.
await writableStream.close();
}
```

**My Dart Function file_saver.dart**

```
class FileSaver {
 Future saveAs2(List<String> finalLines, String fileName) async {
   await js.context.callMethod(
     'saveFile',
      [
        html.Blob(
        finalLines,
        'text/plain',
        ),
      fileName
      ],
   );
  }
}
```

Error :

```
app.js:19 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: window.showSaveFilePicker is not a function
at saveFile (app.js:19:36)
at lz.la (main.dart.js:41242:19)
at main.dart.js:41902:19
at au6.a (main.dart.js:5401:62)
at au6.$2 (main.dart.js:37029:14)
at Object.H (main.dart.js:5387:10)
at a2R.TA (main.dart.js:41904:10)
at a2R.u9 (main.dart.js:41898:21)
at main.dart.js:42628:13
at au6.a (main.dart.js:5401:62
```

Comment: Run your release app, right click on the screen, click on inspect element, click on console tab, now you can see java script errors, so click on save button in your app, and check the error in console, add the error at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, you must run your app on HTTPS hosts to use this function:

[image]

Is your hosting supports HTTPS?

Do you check your URL and are you sure it starts with https?

[image: browser support showSaveFilePicker]
And do you run your app on a browser that supports `showSaveFilePicker` function?